# What makes Gotham work as a major city?

Tags: dc, batman

Gotham city is described since the 70's as a crime-ridden city. Corruption is rampant, thugs walk free and cops do look out for the mafia. And it rains **all the time**, and it's common to quite every version of Gotham since Dennis O'Neil (who wrote "Batman's Gotham City is akin to 'Manhattan below Fourteenth Street at eleven minutes past midnight on the coldest night in November.'")

Such a high crime rate is bound to have [effects on the economy](http://www.encyclopedia.com/law/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/economic-and-social-effects-crime), but Gotham still is a major city of DC Comics' USA, with many big companies despite the risk to see their goods stolen by the mob or their buildings blown up by some batvillain.

Does any part of the canon provide an in-universe explanation for this? If not, is there any study or **informed** guess that would justify all this? I know Gotham City is based on Chicago and/or New York, so answers using these similarities might be good enough.

Comment: Ask Chicago. They managed.

Comment: Or Detroit. Oh wait, never mind.

Comment: ..plus, you know, **it's not real**.

Comment: [**QUORA:** *DC Comics: Why would anyone want to live in Gotham City?*](https://www.quora.com/DC-Comics-Why-would-anyone-want-to-live-in-Gotham-City)

Comment: Are you after an in-universe economic explanation?

Comment: In the Nolan film series we learn that Gotham has been declining due to the deliberate machinations of the League of Shadows.

Comment: @Chenmunka exactly

Comment: @Valorum  -  [the source](https://absorbascon.blogspot.com.tr/2011/04/why-do-people-live-in-gotham-city.html) for the answer on Quora. It's not really an answer though, as it doesn't provide any references or examples.

Comment: @Gallifreian - After some consideration I've voted to close as "too broad". There are simply too many canon descriptions of Gotham's economy for this to be sensibly answered.

Comment: @Valorum I'd be happy to discuss in chat to improve my question if you think it's too broad. If you think *the canon* is too broad, I'd be happy with any part of it, even "obsolete" one.

Comment: Seriously, all of these descriptions are, individually or grouped in bunches, SOP for major US cities.

Comment: @Trajan - I am, alas banned from chat because I made a sarcastic comment toward a Community Manager.

Comment: This question seems too broad, since there are many Gothams in different universes. Try to narrow it down to one.

Comment: @Gallifreian Is this really necessary ? I mean Arkham Asylum's Gotham, Batman TAS's Gotham, New 52's Gotham... they all look quite the same. I edited my question to rule out pre 70's (sorry Mr West !) Gothams, is it narrow enough ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grant Morrison said in a [Gizmodo interview](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5301435/grant-morrison-tells-all-about-batman-and-robin) that it doesn't make sense for Gotham to be "so bloody awful" :

> If Gotham really was an open sewer of crime and corruption, every
>   story set there would serve to demonstrate the complete and utter
>   failure of Batman's mission, which isn't really the message we want to
>   send, is it? You've got Batman and all his allies as well as
>   Commissioner Gordon and the city still exudes a vile miasma of
>   darkness and death? I can't buy that. **It's simply not realistic and
>   flies in the face of in-story logic** (and you know I like my comics
>   realistic!) so my artists and I have taken a different tack and we
>   want to show the cool, vibrant side of Gotham, the energy and
>   excitement that would draw people to live and visit there.
>
> Gotham needs as many faces as Batman - it should be the loudest,
>   sexiest, jazziest city on Earth. It has the best restaurants, the best
>   theaters, the best art, the best criminals, the best crimefighters etc
>   etc. People put up with the weird crime for the sheer buzz.

So the answer to the question might as well be : "no, there is no in-universe explanation"